# How many copies of program/class gets loaded into memory when multiple users accessing it at the same time

Tags: linux, memory, jvm, loading, sharing

We are trying to setup Eclipse in a shared environment, i.e., it will be installed on a server and each user connects to it using VNC. There are different reasons for sharing Eclipse, one being proper integration with ClearCase.

We identified that Eclipse is using large amounts of memory. We are wondering whether the Eclipse(JVM?) loads each class once per user/session or whether there is any sort of sharing of objects that are already loaded into memory?

This makes me think about a basic question in general. How many copies of a program gets loaded into memory when two or more users are accessing the host at the same time.

Is it one per user or a single copy is shared between users?

**Two questions here:**

> 1) How many copies of a program gets loaded into memory when two or
>   more users are using it at the same time?
>
> 2) How does the above holds in the world of Java/JVM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a single copy of a program (i.e. text segment) is loaded into RAM and shared by all instances, so the exact same read-only memory mapped physical pages (though possibly/probably mapped to different addresses in different address spaces, but it's still the same memory). Data is usually private to each process, i.e. each program's data lives in separate pages RAM (though it *can* be shared).

**BUT**

The problem is that the actual program here is only the Java runtime interpreter, or the JIT compiler. Eclipse, like all Java programs, is rather *data* than a *program* (which however is interpreted as a program). That data is either loaded into the private address space and interpreted by the JVM or turned into an executable by the JIT compiler, resulting in a (temporary) executable binary, which is launched. This means, in principle, each Java program runs as a separate copy, using separate RAM.

Now, you might of course be lucky, and the JVM might load the data as a shared mapping, in this case the bytecode would occupy the same identical RAM in all instances. However, whether that's the case is something only the author of the JVM could tell, and it's not something you can rely on in general.

Also, depending on how clever the JIT is, it might cache that binary for some time and reuse it for *identical* Java programs, which would be very advantageous, not only because it saves the compilation. All instances launched from the *same* executable image share the same memory, so this would be just what you want.
It is even likely that this is done -- at least to some extent -- on your JIT compiler, because compiling is rather expensive and it's a common optimization.

Answer (score 2):

Linux allows for sharing binary *code* between running processes, i.e. the segments that hold executable parts of a program are mapped into [**`virtual memory`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) space of each running copy. Then each process gets its own *data* parts (stack, heap, etc.).

The issue with Java, or almost any other interpreted language, is that run-time, the JVM, treats byte-code as *data*, loading it into heap. The fact that Java is half-compiled and half interpreted is irrelevant here. This results in a situation where the JVM executable itself is eligible for code sharing by the OS, but your application Java code is not.